# Редактирование главной страницы opencart

Tags: opencart

Всем привет!

У меня такой вопрос, как можно изменить вид главной страницы opencart?
На главной странице выводится описание и список популярных товаров, нужно к цене товаров добавить единицы измерения(сейчас цена 300 руб., а нужно сделать 300 руб./шт.), эта информация находится в бд. В исходниках главной страницы, в папке common, я ничего не нашел, т.е. там даже нет работы с бд(с моделью). Как это понять, и как на страницу выводятся товары, повторюсь, в исходниках такого я не нашел. Помогите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На главной странице, в OC, все выводится с помощью модулей. В админке сайта можно нужный модуль "повесить" на схему, например "Главная". По этому, смотреть Вам нужно именно нужный модуль. В вашем случае, я полагаю, надо смотреть модуль "Рекомендуемые" (featured) или "Последние товары" (latest) или "Акция" (special) или "Лидеры продаж" (bestseller).
Логика здесь такая: контроллеры расположены в директории `catalog/controller/extension/module/` (или без extension, в зависимости от версии), "вьюхи" - внешний вид: `catalog/view/theme/название_вашего_шаблона/template/extension/module/` вот их и надо править.
Только вот ваши

> 300 руб.

формируются в `system/library/cart/currency.php` и передаются дальше уже в отформатированном виде, в том числе и с символом валюты. Его можно указать в админке, в разделе Локализация-Валюты, и если там поменять, например, руб. на руб/шт, или вносить правки в `currency.php`, то это будет глобально везде: и в товарах, и в корзине, и доставке и т.п., что не очень правильно.
Правильнее всего, наверное, будет внести правки в шаблон вывода нужного модуля. Например, для модуля рекомендуемые `catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/featured.tpl`:

```
<?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <p class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price'] . '/шт'; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special'] . '/шт'; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price'] . '/шт'; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
          <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax'] . '/шт'; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант для ленивых маргиналов (oc2.x):

\catalog\view\theme\default(ваша_тема)\stylesheet\stylesheet.css:

```
p.price:after {
    content: '/шт.';
}
```